# R - 3.5.0 - Unable to install package "tm" on Linux

Tags: r, gcc, tm

I am trying to install package "tm" in R 3.5.0 on a Linux machine. The installation is failing because of some G++ compiler errors. The log is as mentioned below.

```
 > install.packages("tm")
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rediris.es/src/contrib/tm_0.7-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 511317 bytes (499 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 499 KB

* installing *source* package ‘tm’ ...
** package ‘tm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -m64 -std=gnu++0x -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG  - 
I"/usr/lib64/R/library/BH/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" - 
I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 - 
fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic - 
c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG  - 
I"/usr/lib64/R/library/BH/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" - 
I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 - 
fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic - 
fpic -fPIC   -c copy.c -o copy.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG  - 
I"/usr/lib64/R/library/BH/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" - 
I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 - 
fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic - 
fpic -fPIC   -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG  - 
I"/usr/lib64/R/library/BH/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" - 
I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 - 
fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic - 
fpic -fPIC   -c remove.c -o remove.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG  - 
I"/usr/lib64/R/library/BH/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" - 
I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 - 
fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic - 
fpic -fPIC   -c scan.c -o scan.o
g++ -m64 -std=gnu++0x -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG  - 
I"/usr/lib64/R/library/BH/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" - 
I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 - 
fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic - 
c tdm.cpp -o tdm.o
tdm.cpp: In function ‘Rcpp::List tdm(Rcpp::StringVector, bool, 
std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, 
std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, unsigned int, unsigned 
int, unsigned int, unsigned int)’:
tdm.cpp:63: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
tdm.cpp:67: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
tdm.cpp:67: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘return’
tdm.cpp:67: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
tdm.cpp:67: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘return’
make: *** [tdm.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tm’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/tm’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpCMwqqC/downloaded_packages’
 Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
 Making 'packages.html' ... done
 Warning message:
 In install.packages("tm") :
 installation of package ‘tm’ had non-zero exit status
```

I also tried to download and install the tm tar file from the cran website. That installation also gave me the same error message.

Comment: Installing from CRAN shouldn't give the same error as CRAN provides pre-compiled binaries and there shouldn't be any need for compiling from source. Are you *sure* you get the same error when doing `install.packages("tm")`? Why do you want to compile from source?

Comment: In general, CRAN does _not_ provide binaries for Linux. You may be considering the Windows situation which does not apply here.

Comment: What does `g++ --version` say?  Maybe your compiler is too old...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Right ... Linux ... Yeah, I missed that bit. Coming from Mac I forgot...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel .. my g++ version is 4.4.7.

Comment: @Neha. That is _very_ old. Consider picking an older source version of `tm` off the Archive section of its CRAN page.